# randomise image only on "revisit"

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, random

## Current Situation

I've currently got three divs. Let's call them `LeftDiv`, `CenterDiv` and `RightDiv`. `LeftDiv` and `RightDiv` both contain an image that randomises every time the page gets "reloaded", ie when you press F5, or visit a different page on my website. This is done using javascript.

Visiting different pages on my site is done with page IDs, like:

- Homepage is website.com/index.php
- About page is website.com/index.php?page=about
- etc
- etc

Visiting different pages basically only changes the content on my `CenterDiv` (which is obviously located in between the `LeftDiv` and the `RightDiv`). However, the background images also once again randomise. Which is probably because the page refreshes.

## Desired Situation

What I basically want is those images to only randomise (again) when the visitor either refreshes or revisits the website all together (like entering the web-address in the browser again). What this most likely would require I believe is to not have the entire page refresh when a new page ID gets visisted, but rather only refresh the CenterDiv. So now we get to...

## The Question

Is there a way to accomplish this? If so, how? What methods are recommended to use?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use `AJAX` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) to update only a portion of the page, in this case your `CenterDiv`

Comment: Looking into it right now - hoping I can achieve what I'm trying. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery makes AJAX calls so much easier. Might want to check it out here

> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

For your problem, I think something like this might work:

```
function changeDivContents(page)
{
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 data: "page="+page, 
 }
 });
}
```

And then, in the link give an `onclick= "changeDivContents('page_you_want_to_load')"`

Comment: Thanks, this actually works. It did break something else on my webpage, but I think I can fix that without too much trouble. xD thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change only content of your `CenterDiv`. This can be achieved with AJAX calls. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Comment: Thank you, shall look into it.